# How to backup the code from a standalone Google Apps Script project?

Tags: google-apps-script

What are choices to backup my code from a Google Apps Script project?

I mean, saving my whole project code to another place with some automation, etc.

Script files are not included in Drive sync, neither they can be downloaded

Thanks, Fausto

Answer (score 4):

Dan Gottlieb provided a method of utilising Drive Syncing and alternative editors for GAS projects http://gotjs.blogspot.co.nz/2012/08/use-any-editor-with-google-apps-script.html

Comment: that's a great idea as a workaround, thanks a lot for pointing that out // hopefully Google would bring some support on this at some point